# NSData to cv::Mat conversion

Tags: opencv, nsdata

Instead of a UIImage-to-cv::Mat-conversion, I would like to create a NSData-to-cv::Mat-conversion:

Code that works :

```
// converts original image to cv::Mat
cv::Mat cv_src = [self.image CVMat];
```

Test-code (that does not work yet :(... what could be wrong ?)

```
// converts original image to NSData
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1.0);

// converts NSData to cv::Mat
cv::Mat cv_src_TESTTEST = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1,
                                      (int)[data length],
                                      CV_8UC1,
                                      (void*)data.bytes),
                              cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

// converts cv::Mat to a Test-image
UIImage *TestImage = [[UIImage alloc] UIImageFromCVMat:(cv_src_TESTTEST)];

// convert Test-image to cv::Mat
cv::Mat cv_src = [TestImage CVMat];
```

This test-code actually takes a detour, starting from the original image (self.image) and then converting as follows:

1. creating a NSData from the original image (self.image)
2. conversion of this NSData to a cv::Mat
3. conversion of cv::Mat back to a UIImage
4. conversion if UIImage again to a cv::Mat

This detour is only done in order to check for equality to the initial working-code...What I finally need is only conversion 2 (i.e. NSData to cv::Mat). Unfortunately, the "cv_src" from the first code-snipped compared to the second is unfortunately not the same, why ?? My assumption is that "imdecode" is not correctly working here - any suggestions are very much appreciated !

Comment: The problem with your question is that there isn't a clear question asked and answered. You should possibly break this into pieces or spend time clarifying it.

Comment: I think your question is about imdecode being problematic, but you don't specify how it is not meeting your expectations. Provide examples. Also the code that works at the beginning is pointless. If you have working code why are you messing with this? Just delete that.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with a NSData-Category (see code below...). Not sure if all is correct. Please give me some comment on that ? (...especially the last method "- (NSData *)NSDataFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat" (any suggestions if the commented detour via an image is better or not ?? Thank you !

### NSData+OpenCV.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (NSData_OpenCV)

- (NSData *)NSDataFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat;

@property(nonatomic, readonly) cv::Mat CVMat;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) cv::Mat CVGrayscaleMat;

@end
```

### NSData+OpenCV.mm

```
#import "NSData+OpenCV.h"

@implementation NSData (NSData_OpenCV)

// cv::Mat from NSMutableData
- (cv::Mat)CVMat {

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self];

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to backing data
                                                cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                8,                          // Bits per component
                                                cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
CGContextRelease(contextRef);

return cvMat;
}

- (cv::Mat)CVGrayscaleMat {

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self];

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

cv::Mat cvMat = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1); // 8 bits per component, 1 channel

CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to backing data
                                                cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                8,                          // Bits per component
                                                cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                kCGImageAlphaNone |
                                                kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
CGContextRelease(contextRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

return cvMat;
}

// NSData from cv::Mat
- (NSData *)NSDataFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat {

return [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];

/*
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                 // width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                 // height
                                        8,                                          // bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                       // bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                              // bytesPerRow
                                        colorSpace,                                 // colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,// bitmap info
                                        provider,                                   // CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                       // decode
                                        false,                                      // should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   // intent
                                        );


    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalImage, 1.0);
 */

}

@end
```

Comment: Aren't you getting trouble from the compiler about cv::Mat in the header being undeclared?

Comment: If it were me... I would certainly not being handling this NSData->Mat. Maybe, UIImage->Mat, but only for testing within Xcode. If you're using OpenCV for image processing you probably want to avoid any unnecessary conversions between UIImage, CGImages, and Mats. Stick to Mat. As an aside, I have a method like this I use when I want to preview the image in Xcode.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! My code above seems to work tough. I use the following header:`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (NSData_OpenCV)

- (NSData *)NSDataFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat;

@property(nonatomic, readonly) cv::Mat CVMat;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) cv::Mat CVGrayscaleMat;

@end`

Answer (score 1):

cv::Mat can be converted to NSData in the following manner:

```
[NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];
```

And to convert back use following initializer, you have to provide width(cols), height(rows) and type of the image

cv::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)

```
cv::Mat cvMat = cv::Mat(1280, 720, CV_8UC4, (uchar*)data.bytes);
```